# Using $_SESSION variables on a function

Tags: php, session

I have a function on my page to login it works like this:

```
    function entrarSistema($email,$senha){
    if(isset($email) and (autentica($email,$senha)!=false)){

    $mysqli = connect_db();

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT ID FROM px_user WHERE email = '$email'");

    $id = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $_SESSION['nome'] = autentica($email,$senha);
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $senha;
    $_SESSION['ID'] = $id[0];
    $_SESSION['logado'] = true;

    }

    else{
        if(check_double($email)==1){
            setCodeAlerta(1);
            echo $_SESSION['status'];
        }

        else {
            setCodeAlerta(2);
        }
    }

}
```

This function works fine, and the Session variables are set when i call the function setCodeAlerta(), the Session variable i've  declared wont work. Notice that this 2 functions are on the SAME file Here is the function:

```
function setCodeAlerta($numeroCodigo){
    $_SESSION['status'] = $numeroCodigo;
}
```

My index.php has all the pages included, and i use url_rewrite to add the piece of codes that i need, and has this on its very top:

```
if( !isset($_SESSION) ){ session_start(); }
```

Oddly enough, if i call directly a file named test.php with this code:

```
<?php
    setCodeAlerta(2);
?>
```

The variable is set fine, and everything works well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a comment, but my rep isn't high enough yet.  Out of curiosity are the other session vars available at that point that you are setting? -- I ask because I'm running your code (stripped down) and it's returning OK.  I'm just thinking there's something more to this than just that.  Are you calling session_start() twice anywhere in an include or anything?

Answer (score 0):

I got that. Everything was absolutely fine with my code, i just did a conditional, where my code would never really go to wrong username/password, hence, not accessing my function (wich is working fine). After removing the second part (after the and) part of this conditional, my code worked just fine.

```
    if (isset($_POST['submitLogin']) and autentica($_POST['emailLogin'],$_POST['passwordLogin']){
    entrarSistema($_POST['emailLogin'],$_POST['passwordLogin']);
}
```

I normally ask questions and find my answer minutes after that, i think thats a bad habit of mine. Even so, i spent the last 5 hours debugging it.

Thanks!